# How can I update project information with Bussiness Centrol Rest API?

Tags: drools

I'm planning to update project info in the drools business central (also named workbench).  I found an API which adds a new project, but there is no API for update operations!

Can anyone help?

Official document is [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.30.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html), Section 17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way we can update project through REST API. When you mention update operation I assume you want to create new files(BPMN,DRL) throug REST API, then its not possible through REST API. You can use jgit API's to create new assets and for git repository operation